# Converting a timestamp of type string into "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A" format using jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, type-conversion, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a **string** "20210721235523" into the following date-time format "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A". I do not want to get the current date-time, But convert the timestamp in a given variable to the specified format.

With my limited understanding of this, I've tried the following with no luck. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this is highly appreciated.

```js
var datetimeString = "20210721235523"

var newdatetime = moment(datetimeString,"DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A");
console.log(newdatetime);

var newdatetime1 = new Date(datetimeString).getDate();
console.log(newdatetime1);

var newdatetime2 = Date.parse(datetimeString);
console.log(newdatetime2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

How can I convert a string into DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A format?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your datetime format in order to match the `datetimeString`,so change it from `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A` to `YYYYMMDDhhmmA`

```js
var datetimeString = "20210721235523"

var newdatetime = moment(datetimeString,"YYYYMMDDhhmmA");
//var newdatetime = moment(datetimeString,"DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A");
console.log(newdatetime);

var newdatetime1 = new Date(newdatetime).getDate();
console.log(newdatetime1);

var newdatetime2 = Date.parse(newdatetime);
console.log(newdatetime2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. :)